# Issues submitting data to MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to send form data from a page to MongoDB in Node.js.

The issue I am running into is when I am clicking the 'Add Group' button to submit the data.. the page tries to complete the request but seems to get stuck when trying to push the data to the database. So it then is just sitting there, stuck, trying to take the inputted data and place it into the database.

Here is my Group Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    path = require('path');

    var GroupsSchema = new Schema({
        groupName: {type: String}
    });

    GroupsSchema.virtual('uniqueId')
    .get(function(){
        return this.filename.replace(path.extname(this.filename), '');
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Groups', GroupsSchema);
```

Here is my Group Controller:

```
var Models = require('../models');

module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
        var viewModel = {
            groups: []
        };

        Models.Group.find({}, function(err, groups){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }else{

            viewModel.groups = groups;
            res.render('addGroup', {title: 'Admin Add Product Group', adminloggedin: true, subtitle: 'Add a Group', underheaderp: ''});
            }
        }); 

    },

    create: function(req, res){
        var saveGroup = function(){
            Models.Group.find({}, function(err, groups){
                if(groups.length > 0){
                    saveGroup();
                }else{
                    Models.Group.find({},function(err, groups){
                        if(err){
                            throw err;
                        }else{
                    var newGrp = new Models.Group({
                        groupName: req.body.groupname
                    });
                    newGrp.save(function(err, group){
                        console.log('Successfully inserted Group');
                        res.redirect('admin/addGroup');
                    });
                        }
                });
                    }
            });
        };
        saveGroup();
    }
};
```

My current Routes:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),

    addGroup = require('../controllers/addGroup');

module.exports = function(app){

    router.get('/admin/addGroup', addGroup.index);
    router.post('/admin/addGroup', addGroup.create);

    app.use(router);
}
```

And my addGroup handlebars page

```
<!-- Add a Product Group Form -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="/admin/addGroup" method="post">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="newGroupName">Group Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="groupname">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="groupImageFolder">Image Folder Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="groupImageFolder">
                </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Add Group</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, I have yet to find a great way to debug my applications as I am still a new programmer. Any recommendations would be great as well.

The problem must be in my controller :create 
Possibly where I am defining my var newGrp and trying to set it to my group models?

How can I fix this to make it so it saves the inputted data to MongoDB?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you call `saveGroup()` if `groups.length > 0`? It's called recursively and never ends.

Comment: I was attempting to do a poor effort check to see if it already exists but that was quite the mistake. I took that out and replaced it with if(err){saveImage();}

Comment: And it now works perfectly fine!!!

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake. Also use `Models.Group.count()` instead of `Models.Group.find()`, because `find()` loads **all** the records, but `count()` returns only the number of records. And do not call `Models.Group.find()` twice.

Comment: Thank you! I am not even sure how I ended up calling that twice but it is fixed and still working. Thanks again for your help